# proper download url for mysql for mac for this scenario?

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a system for a client and I think he may only have a Mac.  I recently downloaded and installed MySQL on my Windows laptop for the first time.  I think I stumbled around a bit trying to get the correct download and understand the install process.  When I google MySQL downloads, I get the following url:

https://www.mysql.com/downloads/

The header on the page says "MySQL Enterprise Edition."  Usually, the "Enterprise Edition" of a company's software costs money, but in the case of MySQL is it free?  The following tool was installed with my local install of MySQL:

MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

This is the standard client tool for MySQL, I got the hang of it pretty quickly, so I'd like to simply standardize on it.  Can you provide a good download url for the latest free version of the Mac version of MySQL?  Can you also provide a good download url for the latest free version of the Windows version of MySQL just so that I have it for reference?

Like I mentioned, it was my first time installing MySQL recently, but I think at the end of the installation, a Window popped up asking how I wanted to configure the MySQL installation, but it so happened that the MySQL installation was already complete.  Or does this scenario most likely seem to indicate I had already installed MySQL and the configuration popup was just the installer's handling of my attempt to install MySQL on my machine when I had previously installed it?

Comment: Questions asking us to find links to off-site resources are off-topic. Questions about the proper version to download or any pricing should be addressed to the vendor. This site is for specific questions about programming (code) or use of programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, etc.).

Comment: Installing MySQL and Configuring MySQL are two different thing. One is just installing it into your PC and the other is how you configure things like user, password, port etc.

Answer (score 2):

Look all the way down to the bottom of this image:

[image]

Click on "MySQL Community (GPL) Downloads". It takes you to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ which is where you can download the Community Edition of MySQL Server.

They don't restrict downloads of their free product, they just put it in a smaller font. :-)

It's understandable that they would want to promote their paid product.